# Simplify doesn't reduce to simplest form

Tags: simplifying-expressions

After applying Simplify function, I am assuming that it will reduce to the simplest form. The following is the output of simplify on a function which I know should be independent of `r`.

```
Simplify[-((3.9269908169872414*(1 + lambda1)*(Sqrt[2]*l*Sqrt[(-r^2)*Cos[alpha]^2*(-2 + lambda1^2 + lambda1^2*Cos[2*alpha])]*Sec[alpha]^2 - 2*l*r*Tan[alpha]))/
(l*(-1 + lambda1)*r))]
```

From the numerator and denominator we can take `r` common and make the equation free of this variable. I can do it by hand from this step, but wondering if there is any other function which is useful

Comment: I highly recommend carefully reading the online documentation.  Compare `Simplify[(r + Sqrt[r^2])/r]` and `Simplify[(r + Sqrt[r^2])/r, Assumptions -> r \[Element] Reals]`.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer.  Are you sure that your function is independent of `r`?

```
eq = -((3.9269908169872414*(1 + λ1)*(Sqrt[2]*l*Sqrt[(-r^2)*
  Cos[α]^2*(-2 + λ1^2 + λ1^2*Cos[2*α])]*Sec[α]^2 - 2*l*r*Tan[α]))/(l*(-1 + λ1)*r));

Simplify[eq] /. {r -> -1, α -> π/3, λ1 -> 3^0.5}
(* 80.08039386514234 *)

Simplify[eq] /. {r -> 1, α -> π/3, λ1 -> 3^0.5}
(* 21.45747686573111 *)
```

It appears that the function depends on the sign of `r`:

```
Simplify[eq, Assumptions -> r > 0]
(* -((5.553603672697958` (1 + λ1) Sec[α] (Sqrt[-Cos[α]^2 
   (-2+λ1^2+λ1^2 Cos[2 α])] Sec[α] - 1.414213562373095` Sin[α]))/(-1 + λ1)) *)

Simplify[eq, Assumptions -> r < 0]
(* (5.553603672697958` (1 + λ1) Sec[α] (Sqrt[-Cos[α]^2 
   (-2+λ1^2+λ1^2 Cos[2 α])] Sec[α] + 1.414213562373095` Sin[α]))/(-1 + λ1) *)
```

Also note that the variable `l` drops out completely.

Comment: Great, this works. r is a physical quantity which is >0.

Comment: OK.  So you just need to use `Simplify[eq, Assumptions -> r > 0]`.